# React Fetch and expressJS post method do not want to work, what am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, express, post, backend

I have been learning react, and now I was trying to work with expressJS, but The Post method would not work, cause I never get the result Posted to the server. I am sure that the fectching of the post method is correct,maybe the problem is in my express file, and yes I set proxy in JsonFile.maybe I am missing something.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    res.json(cars);
})

// GET method route
app.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    res.send(console.log(req))
})


// GET method route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello this is John Server')
})

// POST method route
app.post('/info', function (req, res) {
    const info = {
        first_name: req.body.name

    };

    console.log(info)

})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

```html
import React from 'react'

class UserForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: '' };
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert('A form was submitted: ' + this.state);

        fetch('/info', {
            method: 'POST',
            // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default UserForm;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlDik.png)

Comment: your input value should be : *value={this.state.name}*

Comment: I added that it would work. {Name : undefined}

Answer (score 0):

Their is a small problem. You did the `JSON.stringify()` that's means your converted the json to object your you have have to again convert it to `JSON` again in backend site
you can try `JSON.parse()` and then you will be able to access your object keys